# WPF - Get index of each item selected in a ListView

Tags: arrays, wpf, indexing

I'm trying to get an int list of selected indexes in a ListView. Something like this:

```
            List<int> SelectedIndexes = new List<int>();
            foreach (var item in Client_List.SelectedItems)
            {
                SelectedIndexes.Add(item);
            }
```

and the output should be something like: 1 5 7 9 12, i cant figure out how to do it in wpf, in windows forms you could just use client_list.SelectedIndices.

What im trying to do is open a new window and send a client info array to it. Below is win forms code.

```
            List<Networking.ClientInformation> SelectedClients = new List<Networking.ClientInformation>();
            for (int i = 0; i < client_list.SelectedIndices.Count; i++)
            {
                SelectedClients.Add(Connections.Clients[client_list.SelectedIndices[i]]);
            }
```

Comment: `var selectedIndices = listView.SelectedItems.Cast<object>().Select(i => listView.Items.IndexOf(i));`. However, you typically don't need to do this. Your ListView's ItemsSource should hold a collection of Client objects. SelectedItems would then already contain what you need, i.e. a collection of selected Clients.

Answer (score 2):

Give a try on this.

```
List<int> SelectedIndexes = new List<int>();
foreach (var item in Client_List.SelectedItems)
{
   int index = Client_List.Items.IndexOf(item)
   SelectedIndexes.Add(index );
}
```

Comment: IndexOf doesn't work if as Items you have strings with duplicates.

Comment: `Items` with duplicates? something wrong on your data.

Comment: To be honest, we are not here to give solution for each and every requirements.  Selecting one among the options (1. "Pizza", 2."Pizza") not making any sense for me.  If you want to be precise in uniqueness, Pls use `Hashset`